# problem with magic numbers in java assignment

Tags: java

I'm doing a project in school, I'm stuck at magic numbers now and would appreciate some help. Everything seem to be working fine, the only problem is with my switch case (case 2, case 3, case 4) because the error I receive is that magic numbers are being used. I tried a couple of things. As declarating the numbers but nothing seem to work.

Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgramSkeleton {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    void initialize () {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the dog register!");
        System.out.println("Type 0 to exit");
        System.out.println("Type 1 to register new dog");
        System.out.println("Type 2 to increase age");
        System.out.println("Type 3 to list dogs");
        System.out.println("Type 4 to remove dog");
    }

    int readCommand() {
        System.out.println("> ");
        int command = input.nextInt();
        return command;
    }

    void handleCommand(int command) {
        switch(command) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("you have chosen register new dog");
            break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("you have chosen increase age");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("you have chosen list dogs");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("you have chosen remove dog");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("unknown command!");
        }
    }

    void runCommandLoop() {
        int command;
        do {
        command = readCommand();
        handleCommand(command);
        } while(command != 0);
    }

    void closeDown() {
        System.out.println("Welcome back!");
        input.close();
    }

    void start() {
        initialize();
        runCommandLoop();
        closeDown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProgramSkeleton program = new ProgramSkeleton();
        program.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no "magic numbers are being used" error; perhaps you have a style checker that warns about their use. Regardless, you have what appears to be a perfect use case for an enumerated type.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs just fine on my machine, so I think there must be something weird about that student server.

Someone might be able to help you, if you provide some more information, like the text of the error message and what this server is and what it expects (if you have any previous experience with it).